# Ping MySql Server (No Login)

Tags: c#, mysql, ping, status

I am writing a utility app for a mmorpg game that I play. I want the app to check the server status and report it to the user. I know that the server is MySql and I have the IP address/port.

Is there a way to *ping* the server from my app (written in C#). Can I do it without logging in (I don't want the user to have to login to use my application)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say just try to log in with a bogus username and password.  The error you get for the invalid login attempt should be different than the error you would get if MySQL was unavailable.

Comment: I was thinking that my app could just execute a normal ping command to the ip address/port of the server rather than trying to login?

Answer (score 0):

Ping may be disabled on the server. Try to open a socket connection to MySQL using your ip address and port. If you can open a connection you know the server is up. Checkout this link for details on socket connections from c# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145128.aspx.

You might try to connect using telnet first to verify that you can establish a connection to the MySQL server. telnet ipaddress portnumber provides similar functionality to doing it in c# but allows you to quickly test connections from the command line before trying to get it working in your code.